# How can I produce serial no for repeating numbers

Tags: awk

I have a pipe delimited text file like below

```
user     |amount|dept|flag
AAAAAAAAA|100.00|SALES|OK
BBBBBBBBB|250.00|ACCOUNT|OK
CCCCCCCCC|200.00|MARKETING|OK
DDDDDDDDD|175.00|ADMIN|OK
AAAAAAAAA|150.00|SALES|OK
BBBBBBBBB|200.00|ACCOUNT|OK
```

I want to arrange serial numbers on basis of first column. As

```
user     |amount|repeatation|dept|flag
AAAAAAAAA|100.00|1          |SALES|OK
AAAAAAAAA|100.00|2          |SALES|OK
BBBBBBBBB|250.00|1          |ACCOUNT|OK
BBBBBBBBB|250.00|2          |ACCOUNT|OK
CCCCCCCCC|200.00|1          |MARKETING|OK
DDDDDDDDD|175.00|1          |ADMIN|OK
```

I have made serials numbers for many files where it auto-increments by `++sl`, but no idea for this one.

Comment: Why does your output contains duplicated numbers (`amount`) while they differ in the input?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
awk -F\| '{$3 = NR==1?"repetation":++T[$1] FS $3; }1' OFS=\| file
user     |amount|repetation|flag
AAAAAAAAA|100.00|1|SALES|OK
BBBBBBBBB|250.00|1|ACCOUNT|OK
CCCCCCCCC|200.00|1|MARKETING|OK
DDDDDDDDD|175.00|1|ADMIN|OK
AAAAAAAAA|150.00|2|SALES|OK
BBBBBBBBB|200.00|2|ACCOUNT|OK
```

That uses a "condidtional operator" to add either "repetation" to the header (NR==1) or the actual counter in front of the third field. The formatting and/or sorting is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Piping the output of your command to `| awk 'NR == 1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -k1"}'` will return the result sorted as requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$2=sprintf("%s|%-10s", $2, (NR>1 ? ++rep[$1] : "repetition")); print (NR>1), $0}
' file | sort -t'|' -k1,1n -k2,2 -k4,4n | cut -d'|' -f2-
user     |amount|repetition|dept|flag
AAAAAAAAA|100.00|1         |SALES|OK
AAAAAAAAA|150.00|2         |SALES|OK
BBBBBBBBB|250.00|1         |ACCOUNT|OK
BBBBBBBBB|200.00|2         |ACCOUNT|OK
CCCCCCCCC|200.00|1         |MARKETING|OK
DDDDDDDDD|175.00|1         |ADMIN|OK
```

The above uses a common idiom of classifying types of line so that you can then sort them by their classification first and then by the values within each classification. In this case I used `NR>1` to classify the header line as type `0` and all the other lines as type `1` (the most common application of this approach) so a sort on the first field output would print the header line first. The `cut` at the end just removes that classification again.

Answer (score 0):

sort -k1 yourfile.txt |awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { slno=0 }
{
user=$1;
{
if (user!=x)
slno=1;
{
printf ("|%9s|%10.2f|%3s|%10s|%3s|\n",$1,$2,slno,$3,$4);
slno++;
x=user;
}
} 
}'